# create new object in array (which is in a object which is in an array which is document) in meteor/mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, meteor, insert-update

i have a problem to create a new object in my mongo-db.
I'm using the meteor-framework and i would like to add new subitems, 
to one subitems-array.

My data-structure looks like this:

```
    { 
       "_id" : "f9d01fd1ef22684353149851", 
       "name" : "Ueberschrift", 
       "items" : [     
                  { "_id" : "be695ec7ffe71152088c57e1",
                    "name" : "asd",
                    "checked" : false,
                    "subitems" : [ ] 
                  },
                  { "_id" : "fe665ec7ffe78852088c22g8",
                    "name" : "asd",
                    "checked" : false,
                    "subitems" : [ ] 
                  } 
                 ] 
     },
     { 
          "_id" : "qw501fd1we522683531qw451",    
          .........
     }, ...
```

For instance, i want to add the subitem

```
 { _id : 1, name : "MySubitemName" }
```

to the item with the _id : `"be695ec7ffe71152088c57e1"`
which is in the object `"f9d01fd1ef22684353149851"`

I used the following command to do this:

```
uid => "f9d01fd1ef22684353149851" and
id => "be695ec7ffe71152088c57e1"

Listitems.update({_id:uid, "items._id" : id}, 
  {"items.$.subitems":  {$push: { _id : 1, name : "MySubitemName" }}});
```

But it doesn't work, the database looks like before.

Has someone an idea?

Comment: I think the syntax would be `{"$push": {"items.$.subitems": {/* doc */ }}}`.  Also note the `""` around `$push`

Comment: @ExplosionPills thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work too,... 
I've changed my command to 

Listitems.update({_id:uid, "items._id" : id}, {"$push" :{"items.$.subitems": {_id : ue_id, name: text}}});

But the only thing i get is:
  > db.listitems.find()
   { "_id" : "f9d01fd1ef22684353149851", "name" : "Ueberschrift", "items" : [     {        "_id" : "be695ec7ffe71152088c57e1",     "name" : "asd",         "checked" : false,      "subitems" : [ ] } ] }

Answer (score 0):

One thing is suggested when defining your doc structure:
Avoid using `_id` in your own schema, as this name is internal of mongodb to represent the ObjectId. If it is strict that you do so, use `id` instead. Please see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/.

So your document can now be like:

```
{ 
    "id" : "f9d01fd1ef22684353149851", 
     "name" : "Ueberschrift", 
     "items" : [     
            { 
                "id" : "be695ec7ffe71152088c57e1",
                "name" : "iop",
                "checked" : false,
                "subitems" : [ ] 
            },
            { 
                "id" : "fe665ec7ffe78852088c22g8",
                "name" : "asd",
                "checked" : false,
                "subitems" : [ ] 
            } 
         ] 
 }
```

the update query:

```
Listitems.update({ id:"f9d01fd1ef22684353149851", "items.id" : "be695ec7ffe71152088c57e1"},  {$push: {"items.$.subitems" :{ id : 1, name : "MySubitemName" }}});
```

I've tested using mongodb console, and I'm assuming the object supplied in the update query matches that of the console.

Please tell us if that worked.

**EDIT to improve comment**:
Since you are meaning the actual object id (`_id`) when querying, please have a look a the code below, adapted as a possible fix for the object referencing:

```
uid => ObjectId("f9d01fd1ef22684353149851") and
id => ObjectId("be695ec7ffe71152088c57e1")

Listitems.update({_id:uid, "items._id" : id}, 
  {$push: {"items.$.subitems" :{ id : 1, name : "MySubitemName" }}});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work too, i don't get any errors, but the dataset isn't updating

Comment: Have you tested with the changed schema (using id instead of _id)? That was an issue when I first tested using your original code.

Comment: No, I haven't changed the _id in my scheme. I'm generating it with var id = new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID().valueOf(); Is that incorrect? Or is mongodb using an internal id-scheme that is not visible?

Comment: You can search for a mongodb's objectId with something like {"_id":ObjectId("f9d01fd1ef22684353149851")}. Try this: Listitems.update({ "_id":ObjectId("f9d01fd1ef22684353149851")}, {$push: {"items.$.subitems" :{ id : 1, name : "MySubitemName" }}});

Comment: Please find the improved answer in the post. Maybe that could get your query working.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that minimongo does not yet support mongo's "$" placeholder operator.  If that is the case, your update may run fine when called from the server but fail if called from the client.  Where are you calling that update from currently?

For an example of a workaround supplied by the Meteor team, see the model.js of their "parties" app here:  https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/examples/parties/model.js

I've pasted the key lines 144-156 below including their comments - in short, they use "$" on the server and replace it with the array index on the client.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    // update the appropriate rsvp entry with $
    Parties.update(
      {_id: partyId, "rsvps.user": this.userId},
      {$set: {"rsvps.$.rsvp": rsvp}});
  } else {
    // minimongo doesn't yet support $ in modifier. as a temporary
    // workaround, make a modifier that uses an index. this is
    // safe on the client since there's only one thread.
    var modifier = {$set: {}};
    modifier.$set["rsvps." + rsvpIndex + ".rsvp"] = rsvp;
    Parties.update(partyId, modifier);
  }
```

Comment: I'm already using the db commands on serverside, and it doesn't work neither